# inserting data using variables in sqlite db

Tags: eclipse, cordova, android-sqlite

hey i'am making my first phonegap application and I have faced a problem in sqlite db 
where , i have had the code to create table in the database and read from it but i need to insert a  variable value in the db instead of static value , here's my code to insert :

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO bus_stations (station_name,station_description,station_lat,station_long) VALUES ("6th October","", + "111" + ,"31.963522")');
```

that works will but this doesn't work , what can i do ??!

```
var x=111;
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO bus_stations (station_name,station_description,station_lat,station_long) VALUES ("6th October","", x ,"31.963522")');
```

Answer (score 0):

By placing your INSERT into single qoutes `'` you are effectively making everthing inside a simple String or text. Your x inthere also becomes nothing but the letter x. I suggest you split the INSERT String and add your variable in as follows:

```
var x = 111;
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO bus_stations station_name,station_description,station_lat,station_long) VALUES ("6th October","",' + x + ',"31.963522")');
```

Notice the `' + x + '` where, before, you had `x`.